# What is the minimum safe room temperature for puppies?

Tags: dogs, temperature, puppy

My puppy is four months old. What is the minimum room temperature that he is comfortable?

I plan to set the room temperature to 68 °F (20 °C) at nights. Is this OK?

=========================

I have  a miniature cockapoo .He is currently 13 pounds.

Comment: please add information about the size and fur of your puppy, and how is it's place shaped. I assume this would make differences, because small bodies with less fur and without some hut will cool down faster than large furry animals in some kind of insulating box.

Comment: (in my area 20°C is a comfortable - means not too hot - summer night. it would be crazy, if we would need to heat the room for a puppy here in summer ;) but it depends, as I said, on the kind of dog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 4 months of age a puppy can regulate their own body temperature well enough. Any temperature that's appropriate for an adult dog of that breed is also appropriate for the puppy. That mostly depends on the thickness of the fur and the body size, but even small dogs with thin fur have no problem with temperatures around 20°C.

Puppies cannot regulate their body temperature for the first 4 weeks of their life and may need an additional heat source if the mother is away. After that time, a room temperature between 20°C / 69°F (winter) and 26°C / 78°F (summer) is recommended ([Source](https://www.abchomeandcommercial.com/blog/what-is-the-best-temperature-for-dogs/)).

In my personal oppinion the lower (winter) temperature only has to be so high for hairless or very small dogs. Dogs with thicker fur (I'm thinking any sheepdog, retriever or terrier) should be fine with lower temperatures, especially if you give them a warm or insulating place to sleep.